# Почему при событии, виден только первый елемент?

Tags: javascript

При клике на объект, виден только первый элемент массива классов - ".itw__content".Почему он не видит второй?

HTML

```
<div class="item__work itw__two">
                <div class="itw__content">
                    <strong>HTML, CSS, JS</strong>
                    <p class="port__el" id="ones">GO!</p>
                </div>
<div class="item__work itw__two">
                <div class="itw__content">
                    <strong>HTML, CSS, JS</strong>
                    <p class="port__el" id="twos">GO!</p>
                </div>
```

JS

```
let itwContent = document.querySelector(".itw__content");
itwContent.onclick = function(event) {
let target = event.target;

let dataItem = data.find(el => (target.id.trim() == el.id));



console.log(target);
}
```

Comment: `querySelector` достаёт только первый элемент. `querySelectorAll` отдаст коллекцию. Не массив! Коллецию.

Answer (score 3):

```
let itwContent = document.querySelectorAll(".itw__content");
Array.from(itwContent).addEventListener('click', function(event){
  // your actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод querySelector() возвращает первый элемент, для получения всех найденных элементов документа, которые соответствуют указанному селектору используйте querySelectorAll() (querySelectorAll возвращает [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList)).

Лучше использовать всплытие событий  - добавить контейнер, куда будет помещен список и уже на него повесить обработчик событий, так можно избежать множественных обработчиков событий.

```
<div class="itw-container">
    <div class="item__work itw__two">
        <div class="itw__content">
            <strong>HTML, CSS, JS</strong>
            <p class="port__el" id="ones">GO!</p>
        </div>
    <div class="item__work itw__two">
    <div class="itw__content">
        <strong>HTML, CSS, JS</strong>
        <p class="port__el" id="twos">GO!</p>
    </div>
</div>

let itwContainer = document.querySelector(".itw-container");
itwContent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   const target = event.target.closest('.itw__content');
   if(target) {
       // your action
   }
});
```